# unhandled promise rejection node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I think I'm missing something small. I keep getting `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning`. I've been combing mdn as well as SO for answers, I need another set of eyeballs on my code.

Thanks

**calling promise**

```
proxySvc.setIfElite(proxy)
  .then(success => {
    console.log(success.msg)
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err.msg)
});
```

**Promise Method**

```
proxySvc.setIfElite = function (P) {
//
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    ProxyVerifier.testAnonymityLevel(P, (error, anonymityLevel) => {
  setCounter();
  if (error || anonymityLevel !== 'elite') {
    reject({
      status: false,
      msg: 'test failure'
    })
  };

 resolve({
      status: true,
      msg: P.ipAddress
    });
 });
```

})

Comment: All your code looks correct, the promise rejection is handled, I think the error is coming from another promise than the one you've posted here.

Comment: ok great. Thanks, I'll check around.